# Formatters give incorrect result after sort or search

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have following code using free-jqgrid. It loads correctly for the first time (Status is “Active” and Partner? is “Yes”). But when I do a sort or search, the values become incorrect(Status is “Retired” and Partner? is “No”).

Why the formatters are giving incorrect values? How to fix this?

**SCRIPT**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">


        function getCurrentPractice ()
        {
            return "Test";
        }

        function getGridCaption() {
            return "<div style='font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; display:inline; padding-left:10px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check' style='margin-right:3px;font-size:14px;'></span>" + getCurrentPractice() + " " + "</div>" +
            "<div style='float:right; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:10px; display:inline;>" +
           "<div style='float:right;width:550px;  padding-bottom:20px;'>" +
                "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='filter' placeholder='Search'  style='width:250px; height:30px; float:right; ' />" +
            " </div>" +
            "</div>";
        }

        $(function () {

            var currentPractice = "P";
            var grid = $("#list2");
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/GetProviders',
                datatype: "json",
                postData:
                {
                    practiceName: function () { return currentPractice }
                },

                colNames: [
                            'Practice',
                            'ProviderID',
                            'Partner?',
                            'Status'
                ],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Practice', hidden: false },
                    { name: 'ProviderID', hidden: false },
                    {
                        name: 'PartnerStatusText',
                        width: 70,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                            var isPartner = rowObject.IsPartner;
                            return isPartner == true ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ActiveStatusText',
                        width: 70,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                            var isActive = rowObject.IsActive;
                            return isActive == true ? 'Active' : 'Retired';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                ignoreCase: true,
                loadonce: true,
                rowNum: 25,
                rowList: [15, 25, 35, 50],
                pager: '#pager2',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortable: true,
                caption: getGridCaption(),

                beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                    //Avoid selection of row
                    return false;
                },
                loadComplete: function () {

                }


            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

            //Filter Toolbar
            $("#advancedSearch").click(function () {
                grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
            });


            //Top Search
            $("#filter").on('keyup', function () {
                var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), f;

                if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
                    grid[0].p.search = false;
                    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: "" });
                }
                f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };
                f.rules.push({ field: "Practice", op: "cn", data: searchFiler });
                grid[0].p.search = true;
                $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
            });


        });
    </script>

</head>
```

**HTML**

```html
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red;">
    <div id="divGrid" style="width: 680px; min-height: 50px; float: left; border: 1px solid silver;">
        <table id="list2"></table>
        <div id="pager2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Server Code**

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult GetProviders(string practiceName)
{

    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    List<Provider> providers = new List<Provider>();
    Provider p = new Provider();
    p.Practice = "Test1";
    p.ProviderID = 1;
    p.IsActive = true;
    p.IsPartner = true;
    providers.Add(p);

    Provider p2 = new Provider();
    p2.Practice = "Test2";
    p2.ProviderID = 2;
    p2.IsActive = true;
    p2.IsPartner = true;
    providers.Add(p2);

    return Json(providers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Oleg, working demo can be found here - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/12/) . It uses `"/echo/json/"` service of JSFiddle to get data from server.

It uses `sorttype` and `additionalProperties`. This can be rewritten without `additionalProperties` - I need to do it when I get a chance to revisit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems be very easy. The data returned from the server contains properties `Practice`, `ProviderID`, `IsActive` and `IsPartner`. The properties are available in `rowObject` during initial loading. You use additionally `loadonce: true` option. Thus free jqGrid will try to save some data locally, but which one? jqGrid saves by default the properties which corresponds the names of columns: `Practice`, `ProviderID`, `PartnerStatusText` and `ActiveStatusText`, but jqGrid have no information that other properties `IsActive` and `IsPartner` need be saved too.

You can solve the problem in two alternative ways:

1. you rename the column names `PartnerStatusText` and `ActiveStatusText` to `IsActive` and `IsPartner`.
2. you add the option `additionalProperties: ["IsActive", "IsPartner"]` to inform jqGrid to read and save locally additional properties.

Moreover, I'd recommend you to use `options.rowData` instead of `rowObject` inside of custom formatter. You can skip the 3-d parameter and to use `formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {...}`.

The final remark: the current code of the custom formatter is very easy. You need to replace some input values (`true` and `false`) to another text. One can use `formatter: "select"` for the case:

```js
    colModel: [
        { name: "Practice" },
        { name: "ProviderID" },
        {
            name: "IsPartner",
            width: 70,
            formatter: "select",
            formatoptions: { value: "false:No;true:Yes" }
        },
        {
            name: "IsActive",
            width: 70,
            formatter: "select",
            formatoptions: { value: "false:Retired;true:Active" }
        }
    ],
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/c9fge9yk/1/

Comment: Perfect. I used `additionalProperties` approach. Nice explanation too -"jqGrid saves by default the properties which corresponds the names of columns". Thank you.

Comment: @Lijo: You are welcome! I recommend you to upgrade always to the last version of free jqGrid (it's 4.14.0 currently).

Comment: @Lijo: The [README](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) contains the URLs. [The wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) contains more detailed information inclusive `integrity` values. I recommend you additionally to read the list of [new features](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#new-main-features-implemented-in-the-version-4140-compared-with-4136). For example [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/) demonstrates auto-generating of `value` of `searchoptions`/`editoptions`.

Comment: On further testing it is found that the last two columns (Partner and Status) does not get sorted even though I set sortable: true and sortname: 'IsActive'. What else need to be done here?

Comment: @Lijo: I'm not sure which scenario you mean. Do you use **server side sorting or client site sorting**? For example the demo from my answer don't use `loadonce: true` and reloads the grid in the original order on sorting. Adding `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` force **client side sorting** even on the first loading of data from the server. See https://jsfiddle.net/c9fge9yk/2/, where I see no problem with sorting by any column.

Comment: @Lijo: In my demo the data come from the server too. Look at the parameter `url: "/echo/json/"`.  It's Echo service of JSFiddle (see [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)). You can use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE to see HTTP traffic. If you have a problem that you should provide the demo, which reproduce it. You can, for example, modify my demo and to use Echo service of JSFiddle too.

Comment: This is my demo where sorting does not work on last two columns- [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/10/).    BTW thanks for `"/echo/json/"` trick. I never thought about it.

Comment: @Lijo: Your code is wrong. Why you not just rename the column `ActiveStatusText` to `IsActive`? The column name will by used only by jqGrid internally for sorting, formatting editing... Usage the wrong name make the code longer without any advantage. For example to solve the problem with sorting you will have can use `sorttype: function (cellValue, item) { return item.IsActive; }`: https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/11/. If you decide to use editing the data you will have to specify `unformat` (see `unformat` [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting)).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it can be rewritten for easy reading and fixing this issue. But I need to test it elaborately. For now, I will do the quick fix `sorttype` and later fix it in the correct way.

Comment: @Lijo: You are welcome! I still think that you go in the wrong direction. If you really want to use the content of the source `IsActive` property in the column `ActiveStatusText` then it would be better to use `jsonmap: "IsActive"` or `jsonmap: function (item) { return item.IsActive; }` https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/13/. The goal of **formatter** to generate HTML fragment, which visualize the data. What do your current formatter is far from it. By usage `jsonmap` to **read** the data you can use **any other formatter** to *format* the data. For example see https://jsfiddle.net/vth5wn64/15/